# Stuck during boot with blacklisting hash (-13) as only message

Tags: boot, grub2

After rebooting my pc, it won't boot and get stuck after only displaying

```
[~] pnp 00:01: can't evaluate _CRS: 12311
[~] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
[~] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
[~] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
```

Both this message should not be blocking as far as I could read online.

From there I can't do anything except rebooting by pressing ctrl+alt+del two times.

I tried opening the grub shell but the delay is too short between the UEFI startup menu and the boot

I tried inspecting the disk and it looks fine

So I'm completely stuck and with no other info that the previous message which doesn't seems relevant.

For info I'm on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 on HP Prodesk.